# BeautifulSoup Scraping How to

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Consider a HTML structure like

```
<div class="entry_content">
  <p>
     <script>some blah blah script here</script>
     <fb:like--blah blah></fb:like>
     <img/>
  </p>
  <p align="left">
      content to be scraped begins here
  </p>
  <p>
     more content to be scraped in one or many paragraphs from this paragraph onwards
  </p>
  -- there could be many more <p> here which also need to be included
</div>
```

The soup

```
    content = soup.html.body.find('div', class_='entry_content')
```

gives me everything within the outermost div tag, including javascript, facebook code and all html tags.

Now how to remove everything before `<p align="left">`

I tried something like:

```
  content.split('<p align="left">')[1]
```

But this is not doing the trick

Comment: try iterating over 'content' and put it in a list.  something like `alist = [];  for ps in content.findAll('p'):  alist.append(ps.text)` then use `alist[1:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [extract](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) or [decompose](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose).

PageElement.extract() removes a tag or string from the tree. It returns the tag or string that was extracted.

Tag.decompose() removes a tag from the tree, then completely destroys it and its contents.